# Compare unicode to non-unicode strings (spanish)

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

How can i make python recognize spanish letters? In program i will have a string stored in unicode, for e.g. in demo x is string. I would like to compare that string with an external string y. Its not comparing strings if they have spanish letters, while in second demo it does where no spanish letters appear

```
x=u"español"
y="español"
if x==y:
    print 'yess'
else:
    print 'noo'

>>> 
noo


x=u"espanol"
y="espanol"
if x==y:
    print 'yess'
else:
    print 'noo'

>>>
yess
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decode the string by the encoding used by the storage or transport mechanism.

```
>>> "español".decode('utf-8')
u'espa\xf1ol'
```

Comment: >>> "español".decode('utf-8')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    "español".decode('utf-8')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 4: unexpected end of data

Comment: That just means you're not using UTF-8 there.